# Microsoft.ServiceHosting.ServiceRuntime is missing on WcfAzureSamples

Tags: wcf, azure

i have the latest SDK of azure and i downloaded Microsoft azure WCF samples. when i try to compile the solution, i get this error:
The type or namespace name 'ServiceHosting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

and i can't find it anywhere.
what do you suggest i should do?

tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure libraries were renamed to

**Microsoft.WindowsAzure** namespace.

Not sure which version of the SDK or samples you are using, but Microsoft.ServiceHosting was changed.

try

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;
```

And see if your reference sync back up.  Again, I don't know what samples are being used so there could be beta-level method calls in there that would need to be redone.